# Qt QString from string - Strange letters

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Whenever I try to convert a `std::string` into a `QString` with this letter in it ('**ß**'), the `QString` will turn into something like "**Ã**" or some other really strange letters. What's wrong? I used this code and it didn't cause any errors or warnings!

```
std::string content = "Heißes Teil.";
ui->txtFind_lang->setText(QString::fromStdString(content));
```

The `std::string` has no problem with this character. I even wrote it into a text file without problems. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the codec to UTF-8 :

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

By default, Qt uses the Latin-1 encoding, which is limited. By adding this code, you set the default encoding to UTF-8 which allow you to use much more characters.

Comment: I edited the answer to add explanations. By the way, could you mark this answer as the accepted answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Though [antoyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389119/antoyo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15579336/147435) works, I wasn't too sure why. So, I decided to investigate.

All of my documents are encoded in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), as are most web-pages. The `ß` character has the UTF code point of [UTF+00DF](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

Since UTF-8 is a variable length encoding, in the binary form, `ß` would be encoded as `11000011 10011111` or `C3 9F`. Since by default Qt relies on [Latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding. It would read `ß` as two different characters. The first one `C3` will map to `Ã` and the second one `9F` will not map to anything as Latin1 does not recognize bytes in between 128-159 (in decimal).

That's why `ß` appears as `Ã` when using Latin1 encoding.

---

Side note: You might want to brush up on how UTF-8 encoding works, because otherwise it seems a little unintuitive that `ß` takes two bytes even though its code point `DF` is less than `FF` and should consume just one byte.